# Enter passcode without touch screen [iTunes]

Tags: itunes, backup, iphone

I have an iPhone 5, which has the screen broken, so I can not type the passcode. After connecting the phone to PC, I wanted/tried to backup the data that is on the phone.

But iTunes says that I need to enter the passcode to access. Is there any possibility to simulate a keyboard or something and enter the passcode on the phone without the screen? Or the only possibility is to replace the screen with a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No your not able to do this.. You always need to prompt the password on your phone via touch.

Or.. you can try to connect with a wireless bluetooth keyboard, but still you will need to touch the screen to do this.